# Is Passport for NodeJS relevant when no there are no immediate plans to integrate external API's?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Is there any point using Passport for Node when there are no plans to integrate external API's like Facebook and Twitter?

I'm looking at arguments for implementing any of the so-called 'strategies' for a generic authentication system in my own application. Or is the only point of Passport to utilise specific authentication strategies from other API's?

Is there even a strategy that acts as a placeholder for future API integration if one was later required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there even a strategy that acts as a placeholder for future API integration if one was later required?

Yes, there is [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local).

> Is there any point using Passport for Node when there are no plans to integrate external API's?

IMHO if you don't need it, leave it out. [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Fewer dependencies is a good thing. When you need it, it is simple enough to add. I also think social login is/was largely a fad that was pseudo-required at one point but these days many people are over it.